# Making a plugin "Suite"?

Tags: plugins

I have gotten to the point in my WordPress workflow where I have a set list of plugin that are pretty much standard for all themes that I make. The problem is I hate seeing the long list of installed plugins right off the bat.

Is there a way that I can somehow group these plugins together, so that they only show 1 in the list of installed plugins, but still have them all be separate directories and still have update checking, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to "group" plugins into one. Although, there is a way to hide plugins.

Just add following snippet to your current theme’s functions.php file:

```
function hide_plugin_trickspanda() {
  global $wp_list_table;
  $hidearr = array('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php');
  $myplugins = $wp_list_table->items;
  foreach ($myplugins as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($key,$hidearr)) {
      unset($wp_list_table->items[$key]);
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_current_active_plugins', 'hide_plugin_trickspanda');
```

Replace plugin-directory/plugin-file.php in above code with your plugin’s directory and file name. You can find this info by clicking on edit plugin link from the plugin list.

If you wanna hide the plugin from your WordPress Multisite, then you above snippet will not remove the plugin from the Network admin list. Here’s a snippet which will work on the WordPress Multisite

```
function mu_hide_plugins_network( $plugins ) {
    // let's hide akismet
    if( in_array( 'akismet/akismet.php', array_keys( $plugins ) ) ) {
        unset( $plugins['akismet/akismet.php'] );
    }
    return $plugins;
}

add_filter( 'all_plugins', 'mu_hide_plugins_network' );
```

Also there is a plugin out there to hide plugins. [Hide Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-plugins/) is its name.

You could also create a mu-plugin (must use plugin). Just a couple of caveats: MU-Plugins can't be upgraded through the admin, so if you want to update for new versions of WP, you (or them, if they have the skills) will have to go through FTP every time. And because these plugins are always on, be sure to test thoroughly! You can read more about mu-plugins on the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I guess since it seems there is no other way of doing it, this will suffice. Thank you!